# How to get discount amount in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, discount, order-items

I am trying to get `discount amount`, but no success

How to get `discount amount` from `$block->getShipment()`

```
<?php
 /** @var $_item \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item */

 $_item = $block->getItem();

 $_item->getDiscountAmount() // this gives me nothing , null

 ?>
```

How to get the discount amount. and there is a discount on that order.

Comment: You have check with echo $_item->getDiscountAmount() ?? Get 0 or null ??

Comment: it gives me null

Comment: you can check $_item->getName() ? it's found item name ??

Comment: Yes $_item->getQty()
$_item->getPrice() , $_item->getName() all works except $_item-> getDiscountAmount()

Comment: you need to find item wise discount right ???

Comment: @LimbaniHimanshu yes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96850/discussion-between-limbani-himanshu-and-summu).

Comment: could you please check $block->getItem(); this function in core file.

Answer (score 1):

If discount is applited through shopping cart rule, then you can get discount amount by this:

```
$_item->getDiscountAmount();
```

But if you have applied discount amount using catalog rule or special price then you need to calculate discount manually by this:

```
$discount = $_item->getOriginalPrice() - $_item->getPrice();
```

Hope this will help